# How to free GPU memory from keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm loading a keras model that I previously trained, to initialize another network with his weights. Unfortunately, the model I load fills my entire memory making the training of the new model impossible. Here is the code :

```
import gc
import keras
from keras.models import model_from_json

def loadModel (path, loss=None, optimizer=None):
    with open(path + '/model.json', 'r') as f:
        model = model_from_json(f.read())
    model.load_weights(path + '/model.h5')
    if loss and optimizer:
        model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

model = loadModel('the/path/to/my/model')

# The GPU memory is filled

keras.backend.clear_session()

# memory still filled

del model
gc.collect()

# memory still filled
```

I checked multiple posts, and usually `gc.collect()` or `clear_session()` does the trick, but for me, it doesn't work so far. Any idea?

**PS:** I'm using tensorflow as backend.

Comment: By default, TensorFlow allocates all  the memory in the GPU and manages it internally, are you sure it is not this?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro totally that, I posted an answer and cited you, thanks.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MatiasValdenegro said, tensorflow allocate the entire memory, that's why I couldn't see the difference after deleting the model. So I basically loaded my pre-trained model, created my new model and initialized his weights with those from the pre-trained model. After that, I deleted the pre-trained model using `del model` and `gc.collect()`. Since the new model has one more layer than the pre-trained one, I had to reduce my batch size to not run out of memory.